# React Native and Couchbase

Tags: react-native, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Technologies:
Frontend:
React Native,
Couchbase Lite
Backend:
Couchbase server

I am building the Message sharing application where user1 sends message to user 2 and below are my usecases,

1. User1 message will be stored to the local couchbase lite DB
2. When "User1 is online", transfer the message to couchbase server
3. When "User2 is online" couchbase server sends the message to user2, once user2 acknowledges that it receives message, remove the message from couchbase server.

Iam aware that couchbase lite/couchbase-server can be used to perform Local only, Remote only, Local and Remove sync operations.

But not sure how to achieve the points,

1. how to detect user1 is online, so that once user1 is online, message will be sent to the server
2. how to achieve the acknowledgement (server-client). ie, server acknowledges to user1 that it receives the message
3. how to detect user2 is online from the server side, so that server sends message when user2 is online
4. how to perform acknowledgement (client-server)
5. remove the message from couchbase server once it recives acknowledgement.)

Does couchbase fits to achieve my usecase or do i need to look any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I believe bundle Sync Gateway (SG) + Couchbase Lite (CBL) could fit your needs:

1. "user1 is online" means that his app CBL starts push replication with SG ("sending message")
2. once user1 app finished replication its CBL could be sure that doc is "sent" to SG
3. the same as point 1. but pull replication
4. once point 3. happened - just act server-side accordingly (see SG web-hooks)

Comment: Hope the suggestion works for Mobile to Mobile communication. My scenario includes 3rd party update too (ie update from web service). So i would like to store my data that received from webservice to the Couchbase DB after all the validations and then deliver this data to Mobile user. Once the message is delivered, i need to remove the data in couchbase db.